# Rails: How to check if user has previously bookmarked pin?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

In my app, I have pins (posts), users and bookmarks. Each user can bookmark a post for later reading. This all works great.

However, I am stuck on how to show if the user has previously bookmarked the pin, on a list of all pins? For each pin in the list, I want to do a check in my view to see if they have bookmarked it.

**pin.rb (model)**

```
class Pin < ActiveRecord::Base

    belongs_to :user
    has_many :bookmarks, dependent: :destroy

end
```

**user.rb (model)**

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base

    has_many :pins, dependent: :destroy
    has_many :bookmarks, through: :pins, dependent: :destroy

end
```

**bookmark.rb (model)**

```
class Bookmark < ActiveRecord::Base

    belongs_to :user
    belongs_to :pin

    validates :pin_id, uniqueness: { scope: :user_id, :message => "has already been bookmarked" }

end
```

A user can bookmark a pin, which creates a single record in the bookmarks table. The bookmarks table stores the `user_id` and the `pin_id`.

I'm having a bit of a brain melt-down on how I would go about checking in the view, if a user has bookmarked a pin or not. I'd basically just like to show a yes or no flag to the user.

Any guidance or advise would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks,
Michael.

**UPDATE:**

I ended up modifying the anser by Lucas. In my Pin model I defined a boolean method:

```
def bookmarked_by?(user)
    return true if bookmarks.any? {|b| b.user == user }
end
```

...that will return true if any bookmarks belong to the given user on this pin. Seems to work okay, but welcome any additional improvements.

Comment: Even simpler, you can just do `bookmarks.any? {|b| b.user == user }`. That will return true or false anyways, so you don't need the explicit `return true if`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I would do, to build slightly on @Tamer's answer is to create a method on the Pin model:

```
class Pin < ActiveRecord::Base
  # ...
  def bookmarked?
    !bookmarks.empty?    
  end
end
```

Then you can simply do this in the view:

```
<% pins.each do |p| %>
  <%= "yes" if p.bookmarked? %>
<% end %>
```

The main reason for this is it encapsulates the logic for understanding whether or not something is bookmarked to the thing that cares about that information, which is the pin. It also keeps logic out of the view, which is super important for clean and maintainable views.

What if, for example, you wanted to check and show pins as bookmarked *only* if bookmarked by the current user, you could do something like the following:

```
class Pin < ActiveRecord::Base
  # ...
  def bookmarked_by?(user)
    return false unless bookmarked?

    bookmarks.any? {|b| b.user == user }
  end    
end
```

I don't like the `bookmarks.any?` call as I think it will cause another db query, and I think there's a better way to do it, offhand, I'm unsure. I'll update once I find it.

However, in the view, you can now do:

```
<% pins.each do |p| %>
  <%= "yes" if p.bookmarked_by? current_user %>
<% end %>
```

### Update:

Was given an incredibly efficient way for distilling the query down into a COUNT query:

```
class Pin < ActiveRecord::Base
  def bookmarked_by?(user)
    bookmarks.for_user(user).any?
  end
end

class Bookmark < ActiveRecord::Base
  scope :for_user, ->(user) { where(user: user) }
end


pins = Pin.includes(:bookmarks) # ... any additional conditions

<% pins.each do |pin| %>
    <%= 'yes' if pin.bookmarked_by? current_user %>
<% end %>
```

See the question I posted here with the brilliant answer from @pdobb: [How does Rails handle a has_many when query uses includes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23901388/how-does-rails-handle-a-has-many-when-query-uses-includes)

Comment: Sounds interesting. Would you mind expanding on your second approach with regard to passing an argument?

Comment: Updated. Unsure I like the logic entirely, but it should work.

Comment: Thanks, but I get an error: undefined method `bookmarked?' for #<Class:0x007fddb8322088> ...am I missing something here? I have it exactly as you do.

Comment: It's okay, I changed the logic to be: def bookmarked_by?(user) return true if bookmarks.any? {|b| b.user == user } end, instead and it seems to work fine.

Comment: Oh, you would have also needed to add the first method (def bookmarked?) I defined earlier. I omitted from the second code block for simplicity.

Answer (score 2):

Well I'd suggest that when you query `Pin`s, include their `Bookmark`s that are associated with the current user. And then check if the Pin has any bookmarks.

```
pins = Pin.includes(:bookmarks).where("bookmarks.user_id" => current_user.id)
```

Now when looping these `pins` to view them, check whether the `pin.bookmarks.length` is `0` or more. And on that basis you can view yes or no.

```
<% pins.each do |p| %>
  <%= "yes" if p.bookmarks.length > 0 %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Is this to be in the model of the pin or the controller?

Comment: The first snippet should be in the controller, where you will be querying posts that are gonna be shown to the user.

Comment: I get an error: undefined method `bookmarks' for #<ActiveRecord::Relation::ActiveRecord_Relation_Pin:0x007fddb95bb230>

Comment: @MichaelGiovanniPumo I'm sorry but I posted the answer blindly because I'm not close to my rails machine right now. I'm going to check the problem once I get close to it (not too long from now).

Comment: Thanks, I'd appreciate that!

Comment: @MichaelGiovanniPumo do you get that error from the linke in the view? Also please checkout the little fix I've applied to the query line.

Answer (score -1):

Maybe this?

```
<%= "yes" if Bookmark.where(pin_id: pin.id, user_id: current_user.id).first %>
```

Probably cleaner to make a helper method, or maybe a Pin class method

```
class Pin
  def bookmarked?(user)
   !!Bookmark.where(pin_id: id, user_id: user.id).first
  end
  ...
```

in the view...

```
<%= "yes" if pin.bookmarked?(current_user) %>
```

Comment: I get an error with this: undefined method `bookmarked?'. Any ideas on that? UPDATE: Just placed within the pin model and it works. So my next question is, is defining helpers in the model a good idea?

Comment: That's going to be incredibly inefficient if you have to run that DB query for _every single pin_ on a given page. Please don't do this...

Comment: @Lukas That's what I thought too. Do you know of a better way? Perhaps my tables need restructuring?

Comment: yep, I agree that @TamerShlash solution is better.