# How does Rails handle a has_many when query uses includes?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, database, performance

If I have a User model that has many Posts, how many queries will Rails perform against the database in the following scenario?

```
class User
  has_many :posts

  # this is the main method in question...
  def has_posted?
    posts.any? {|p| p.posted? }
  end
end

# has an attr "posted" which is a boolean
class Post
  belongs_to :user
end


# some controller
users = User.includes(:posts).all


# in the view
<% users.each do |user| %>
  <%= 'posted!' if user.has_posted? %>
<% end %>
```

Does the fact that I'm using `includes` in the initial query do any magic when I loop over the returned posts in the `has_posted?` method to prevent multiple lookups against the posts table for each user?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Does the fact that I'm using includes in the initial query do any magic when I loop over the returned posts in the has_posted? method to prevent multiple lookups against the posts table for each user?

Yes.

If you don't use the `.includes()` you'll have what's called an N+1 query. I.e. having to look up the first item and N more after it. Using `.includes()` will eager load the post objects into memory at execution time. Execution time will be at the point you call something that executes the query... In your example with the `has_posted?` method, the execution point would be `posts.any?`.

**UPDATE**

However,here's an even better way to do this! i.e. with a database query instead of by looping through a collection of posts with ruby. So like this:

```
class User
  def has_posted?
    posts.is_posted.any?
  end
end

class Post
  scope :is_posted, -> { where(posted: true) }
end
```

In this fashion, you get the database to only select those posts that have `posted` set to true. And then the `.any?` will turn the query into a COUNT query and voila! (Run this on the console and watch the queries generated by each approach.)

Comment: I was confused at the "two examples" until I realized I typed the method name incorrectly in the view. Can you revise your answer to match my updates? Kudos for the explanation around N+1.

Comment: Holy crap, I didn't know about `any?` as part of the AR query set. That's pretty beautiful.

Comment: In ruby/rails, if you feel like something *should* exist then it probably does :) -- gotta love it.